# How to make reactjs serve static pages for SEO

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, react-router, jsx

I have this reactjs webapp - http://52.26.51.120/

It loads a single page and then you can click links to dynamically load other boards on the same page... such as 52.26.51.120/#/b, 52.26.51.120/#/g

Now the thing is, I want each of these to be an individual page, for the purpose of seo. I want you to be able to google "my-site.com g", and you will see the result 52.26.51.120/#/g. This obviously cant work if you are using reactjs and it is all on one page. Google will only render and cache that main page (can it even render that page? does google execute javascript?)

Even more specifically, id want something like my-site.com/g/1234 to load a thread. There could be a thousand threads every day, so im not sure how to handle that.

Are there any solutions to this? to allow react to possibly serve up static pages as html so that they can be cached on google? I am using expressjs and webpack as my server right now, and all the code is executed in jsx files.

Thanks

Comment: Search for "react universal", "react isomorphic" or "react server rendering", you will find a lot of tutorials. If you use JavaScript on the server, you already are halfway there.

Comment: okay I see what you mean, but i cant seem to figure out how to do it with a parameter in the url, so the route in express would be something like ("/:board"), and then it would pass that to the jsx file, which would return a custom html for that parameter

Comment: In regards to server-side rendering the server will only render the initial `index.html` file and Javascript, then pass route handling back to the client via `ReactRouter`. So any request that comes in `app.get('/*')` is then handled by the client vs. the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) service. In a nutshell you will need to connect your server app or web server with prerender service and do little setup (see documentation). After that search engines and crawlers will be served with a static (prerendered) content while users will get classic React.js (or any other single page) app.

There is a hosted service with free tier or [open source version](https://github.com/prerender/prerender)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could do some smart configuration with nginx and it could convert a url of domain/board to a redirection of domain/#/board when detecting the user-agent as a bot instead of a typical user.